# Audio recording stops when sound in other app is playing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, audio-recording

We have functionality for background recording in app.
It is working fine when app in background mode but it is stop  when we open other app  and play sound in it.How can we continue recording even without stop recording when other app play sound.

Note: When Recording start at that time out app in background mode.

Comment: Try AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions  -> Mix With Others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method in appDelegate,

```
func audioSessionSettings() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: i check your code but face one issue i have .key file i open that .key file from my app to Keynote Applicaion when i play key file from keynote then recording audio stop becuase may be .key file containt audio and video at that time my app stop audio recording